# How to change color of MS Fabric control /button without affecting hovering affect

Tags: office365-apps, office-ui-fabric

I am using Microsoft Fabric UI for build my Office WebApp:
http://dev.office.com/fabric/components/button

I want to change the color of a button, but if I change the color of it using some CSS, hovering effect is lost. What is the right way of changing the color of Microsoft Fabric controls?

Answer (score 0):

Even I've had that question for more than a week now. It just seems like no one from the Office Fabric Teams (or even just those who know better) want to answer questions.

If you colorized your button manually using CSS, then just add the `:hover` to the CSS class like so:

```
.btn-color-red {
   background-color: #FF0000; /* red */
}

.btn-color-red:hover {
   background-color: #b50000; / * a darker red when hovered upon */
}
```

I apologize for this manual solution. Even I don't know how to do it using just Office Fabric classes and there are just no useful documentations out there.

Comment: Just started using Fabric and also stuck with colors! How do exactly change button colors? I've added your two classes to a page, but a button has the same color...